# DataTables warning: table id=StudentTable - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am getting JSON object successfully form the server. But when I use to show the data with jQuery DataTables, it shows this alert:

> DataTables warning: table id=StudentTable - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0

When I click OK then it shows the rows without data. How can I resolve this issue?

Here is the code

```js
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#StudentTable").dataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url: "/Students/GetAllStudents",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "JSON"
                  
                },
                serverSide: "true",
                processing:"true",
                column: [
                     {
                         data: "StudentName"
                     },
                     {
                         data: "Registration"
                     },
                     {
                         data: "DeptName"
                     },
                     {
                         data: "Email"
                     },
                     {
                         data: "Date"
                     },
                     {
                         data: "Seasson"
                     },
                     {
                         data: "Address"
                     },
                     {
                         data: "ContactNo"
                     },
                    {
                        render:function(data, type, students) {
                            return "<a href='/Students/edit/" + students.StudentId + "'> Edit</a>";
                        }
                    }
                ]

            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

```html
 <table id="StudentTable" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>Reg No</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Seasson</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Contact No</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error means that DataTables is unable to obtain data for a cell.

You have misspelled option name, it should be [`columns`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns), not `column`.

There are many other reasons for this error, possible solutions are explained in this [technical note](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4).

Comment: Thanks @ Gyrocode.com

The issue has now been resolved.

Comment: @KamolChandraRoy could you please indicate how you solved the error (and post it as answer to this thread)? Thanks in advance